# Basic PHP Upload Form Issue

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload

I want my form to check if the file name equals the users name, in principle everything works fine how I tested it, but the problem I'm having is that the spell check includes the format letters of the image, thus giving a non match.

Example:

`Username` tries to upload a picture which is correctly named `Username.png`

The system would work fine, but it takes into account the `.png` as well, thus gives out a non match. Is there a way I could try and exclude the image format name from the if statement? Because that is pretty much the only problem I'm having with my function, I tried renaming myself to `Username.png` and then the form works great, but in practice nobody will use such a weird username lol. I'm sorry if my question is a bit confusing or too long, hope it is as clear as I think it is. I will include my small snippet of code here:

```
if ( ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) != $ir['username'] )
{
  echo "Sorry, your file is not correctly named.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

I tried adding a .png after the $ir['username'] like so: $ir['username'].png but then the form just gives out a critical error, so I assume this is a bad spot to write it in. Is there a better way I could do this and is there a way at all? Maybe I could make the form not show up the .png for example? I'm unsure how I could handle this at this point, any input would be invaluable. Thank you for your time, have a good day!

Edit: I will include the form itself as well:

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  Select image to upload:
  <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'><br>
  <input type='submit' value='Upload Picture' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe `explode` your string on a `.` and then use the first part? If your filename contains more than one `.` you would have an issue though.

Comment: The file names will only be letters, numbers, or an underscore, so that sounds like something that is worth trying, thank you for the reply.

Comment: You could use a regex or maybe some `strpos` probably. Regex like `'/^' . preg_quote($ir['username']) . '[.]/'` but only if you really don't care what is after the `.`. If this is for security you shouldn't go this way.

Comment: For PHP, you may use pathinfo and then path_parts['filename'] to do what you want: `$path_parts = pathinfo('username.png'); echo $path_parts['filename'];`

Comment: Btw, why do you need uploaded file to have some specific filename? Couldn't you just rename it?

Comment: `$filename = explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` and then `$filename[0]` (the first item of the array) contains everything before the first dot (`.`).

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone, exploding like in the marked answer does work perfectly. I will admit, I'm not fully yet sure how it does it step by step because I haven't yet encountered the explode function, but it's something I definitely need to write down. Pretty much what I did was I added the code above the spell check part, then changed ```( ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) != $ir['username'] )``` to ```( ($filename != $ir['username'] )``` and it works perfectly.

Comment: To answer a previous question about why I need specific names for the files, my current user profile page shows userpic by ```<a href='pics/$username'>``` as an example. I know it's basic, but it works good enough for now. The page will match the username and if it's correct for the uploader it will now go through and if it's not, then it won't. I also have other lines to make sure it's an image, the format is allowed etc. Though I'm sure there's loads of better ways to go about it, which at my current experience level I'm just incapable of doing.But this works for now and I'm happy,thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing that.

The easiest is to split your filename on `.`, remove the last one and glue it again.

```
$filename = explode('.', $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
array_pop($filename);
$filemame = implode('.', $filename);
```